# 4 threads or 8, thread execution time is the same

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, memory

Initially I have (for example 2 000 000 lines of data to process)
I have an `ArrayList<ArrayList<SubsData>> threads`.
SubsData is a class.

In the loop I fill the array according to given amount of threads number;
So if I have more threads, then each ArrayList will have less data to process.

Then here I pass array of data to certain thread and run it.
`

```
for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++) 
{
           ArrayList<SubsData> thread = threads.get(i);
           Worker w = hlrSockets.get(i);
           DButilities db = dbSockets.get(i);
           Collation performCollation = new Collation(thread,w, db);
           new Thread(performCollation, "collateThread #" + i).start();
}
```

`

But it doesn't matter if I run 8 or 16 threads, the thread execution time doesn't varies.

1. *Ok let's say I have 1 processor with 8 cores*
2. *100 lines in ArrayList* 
   **1 thread will process array within 1 minute**
3. *Then I split 100 lines in two different ArrayList objects with 50 lines in each*
4. Pass these arrays to different threads

**2 threads should process data in arrays within 30 seconds**

Am I right ?
If I'm, then why it's not working in my case ?
If you need any part of my code, I will post it here just shout
I need to get rid of it

Here is profiling results.
Please check it out
[image: Threads time line]

[image: Locks and Threads 1]

[image: Locks and Threads 2]

Eventually, I found narrow place in my programm.
It seems like from multiple threads Im reading from a single output stream.

When I comment the line readLine(), my programm runs twice, four times faster accoring to number of threads.

So the question is, what is wrong with this line ?
I create BufferedReader inside a Thread, doesn't it suppose to be specific for each thread ?

Comment: How many cores do you have?  If all the cores are busy, how would adding more threads help?

Comment: What is your hardware? Does your machine have enough cores to run all threads in parallel?

Comment: I have Corei7 with 8 cores.

Comment: Here is output of thread execution
with 2 threads
Thread pool-1-thread-1 started; Subs to process : 893
Thread pool-1-thread-2 started; Subs to process : 889
Thread pool-1-thread-2 finished; Execution time (sec) : 55 processed : 889
Thread pool-1-thread-1 finished; Execution time (sec) : 56 processed : 893

Comment: with 8 threads
Thread pool-1-thread-1 started; Subs to process : 224
Thread pool-1-thread-5 started; Subs to process : 223
Thread pool-1-thread-2 started; Subs to process : 223
Thread pool-1-thread-3 started; Subs to process : 223
Thread pool-1-thread-4 started; Subs to process : 223
Thread pool-1-thread-6 started; Subs to process : 223
Thread pool-1-thread-8 finished; Execution time (sec) : 49 processed : 220
Thread pool-1-thread-5 finished; Execution time (sec) : 49 processed : 223
Thread pool-1-thread-2 finished; Execution time (sec) : 49 processed : 223
etc..

Comment: What I wanted to say is that difference of thread time running is ~4 sec between 2 and 8 threads

Comment: What kind of processing do you threads perform? It seems, that there is an DB connection involved? Maybe, the DB (concurrency + locking) limits the throughput (ie, only a single thread can issue queries to the DB at the same time)?

Comment: I make separate DB connection for each thread, doesn't it work ?
Like : dbSockets.add(i, new DButilities(user, password, database_url));
Then from dbSockets.get(i) I give it to certain thread

Comment: You can open multiple connections, but if, for example, all threads insert/update/delete data in the same table, the DBMS will synchronize those calls to preserve ACID guarantees. Otherwise, your DB might end up in an inconsistent state. Thus, there is only one DB operation at a time. If you do DB read on the other hand, those can be performed in parallel -- DB will not block multiple parallel read. How do you interact with the DB?

Comment: There's no "insert/update/delete", it's only select
I select data by index, so it's quick
It depends only on amount of records in array for which I get info from DB.

Comment: I assume that the code you are using is not taking advantage of hyper-threading on the I7, cause it already fully utilizes one virtual core. Therefore your I7 would not be faster than a quad-core, and thread execution time does not go down after 4 threads, because the processor will pause and resume threads to keep working on all of them. I.e. if you lunch 32 threads, they will be split onto the 8 virtual cores, where 2 cores are sharing one physical core, so one physical core will concurrently work on 8 threads, which takes exactly the same time as if it would work on one thread.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to profile the code to see where most of the time is being spent.

Common reasons that people don't see much speedup in a multithreaded application are:

- A significant part of the application is single-threaded.
- The performance of the multi-threaded part depends on (for example) an external database that is either effectively single-threaded or resource (e.g. CPU or I/O) constrained.
- The threads are contending for something (e.g. a lock, access to memory / cache) and reducing throughput.
- You don't have enough cores to make a significant difference.

Without seeing pretty much all of your code, it is not possible to predict if one of these is your problem ... or something else.

Comment: I tried to run my code several times, with different input values.
each time no difference.
yes I use connection to 2 DBs, but the point is, that even with all locks+concurrencies processing time should vary, when processing 2000 or 1000 lines am I right ?.

Comment: No you are not right (necessarily).  It could well be that the database is the bottleneck.

Comment: What if I put all data that is being processed into an array and then create threads , so that further there will be no need to connect to database ?
would it help ?

Comment: Maybe.  But now your application has a long single-threaded phase while it loads the data from the database into the array.  It would a better idea to profile the application first.  (See the first sentence of by Answer!)  Unless you do that, this is all guesswork; i.e. bad science and bad engineering.

Comment: Re, _A significant part...is single-threaded_.  Good opportunity to invite the OP to Google for "Amdahl's Law".

Comment: I did profiling. It shows that significant amount of time is wasted on readLine() from output stream. Otherwise everything is ok. There's no time spent on selecting from DB, so guesses about DB locks is wrong.
According to this, for example readLine() takes 1sec, and I have 100 records in Array, so its 100 seconds to process, this means thread gonna be finished in 100secs. But if I have 50 records, its gonna need 50sec to accomplish , am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

Multi-thread may be efficient if different use cases :

- when processing has to wait for external events (a server with several external clients)
- for CPU bound processing up to the number of cores

And there are use cases where multi-thread could just be worse :

- for disk IO bound processing (should neither increase nor significately decrease)
- for database bound processing (higher risk of lock contention could decrease performances)